# Google Analytics API v4 showing incorrect goal conversions when using ga:date with ga:keyword dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

So, In my actual google analytics portal i can see for my given view that i have a total of 184 goal completions (i have linked google to adwords). I can see that number in there clear as day, i can also add the `ga:date` dimension and still report on the 184 goal completions.

However, in my code base using the Reporting API V4 using the metric `ga:goalCompletionsAll` and dimensions `ga:campaign`, `ga:adwordsCampaignID`, `ga:adwordsAdGroupID`, `ga:keyword` and `ga:date`. When I use these dimenions I end up with 155 results rather than the 184 I can see in Google Analytics. When I drop the `ga:date` dimension I see 184 as the total as expected when i add up the values by campaign then group. Yet adding that `ga:date` dimension is resulting in my losing 29 entries which from a reporting perspective for my clients is way out.

So if i have `ga:keyword` or `ga:date` the values come out correctly, but together I am losing 29 results.

Is there a reason why the `ga:date` dimension would through off my goal conversions like it is doing?

Comment: what dates are you requesting is the data golden?  What is your starting PageToken? does the response contain a nextpagetoken?

Comment: I don't have a clue what that is, i should've given more details im using PHP with the relevant SDK. Im using the Google_Service_Analytics scope and the date range in my code for the given data is 1-9-16 - 28-9-16 which is the same as what im looking at in analytics. Not sure what these tokens are you're mentioning?

Comment: you might want to read up on the API then the client library just helps you use the api it doesn't do everything for you https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/  If there are more rows in your request for example (nextpagetoken) you will need to fetch them.  Also posting your code might help

Comment: Also I think you are using the relevant client library there is no SDK for PHP.

Comment: Sorry yes that's what i meant. Ive looked at the docs, but i cant see why putting those 2 dimensions together would break the results as to what i would expect?

Comment: Ah i see im getting 1000 limit and i think theres 1200 rows. I need to work out how to request the next page if theres more then.

Comment: set page size to 10000 for now.  But you will still need to get pageing working

Comment: Well i tried to be clever and put max-results to 1000 and start index to 1 then take the total results vs how many results i had and re ran the query with a start index of 2 to get the next page but that gave me the same 1000 rows.. i dont see the nextPageToken field how can i get it? then query it.

Comment: starting index is 0 I was bit by that yesterday you need to take the report that you just ran apply the nextpage token that was returned you to it as as its page token.

Comment: So i can just loop through doing the same request with a new index then? But if i did index 1 then index 2 why did i get way more rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124539/discussion-between-daimto-and-mdixon18).